How to implement content-owner only access in Firestore Database?
I'm trying to restrict document CRUD operations to document creator only. When creating documents (=notes), they get userid from auth based on the current user, so that is working correctly. I have tried to set the firestore rules like so:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /notes/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userid;
    }
  }
}

but I'm getting error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
I have also tried the rule without && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userid; and it's working then, but obviously giving crud access to all authenticated users (not content-owner only).
Here is also the structure of the DB:

Appreciate the help!

Please edit the question to show the query in your app that causes the error.  Security rules are only meaningful when paired with the specific queries you would like to allow or deny.  If the query doesn't match the rule, then it will naturally be denied every time.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

@DougStevenson Fixed it by adding the appropriate query when making a request. I had the idea that Firebase handles the data filtering for me, but apparently not. Well, that's what I get for being lazy and not looking at the documentation deeply enough.

Fixed with adding userQuery to the code:
const userQuery = query(notesRef, where("userid", "==", userid))
const docSnap = await getDocs(userQuery);
const notesData: Note[] = docSnap.docs.map((doc) => ({
     ...(doc.data() as Note),
     id: doc.id
}));

